# ssh is working (very fast very stable) but scp and rsync are neither working

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp

I am sending some files from Server A to Server B.

And I created a key file so that I can use ssh from A to B very easy.

And then I used scp and rsync to send the files.

It was working quite well before but suddenly it fails to work. There's no error message. The machine just went silence after I execute the command (exact the same command as I entered because I keep it in a `.sh` file).

UPDATE2:

On the receiving side, the log from `/var/log/secure` is:

```
Jan 26 04:14:14 localhost sshd[17125]: Accepted publickey for root from *.*.*.* port ***** ssh2

Jan 26 04:14:15 localhost sshd[17125]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

On the sending side, the log of `scp -v` is:

```
➜  ~/megit:(master) ✗ scp -v /root/***.json root@*.*.*.*:/root/***.json
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host *.*.*.*, user root, command scp -v -t /root/***.json
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to *.*.*.* [*.*.*.*] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA **:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**
debug1: Host '*.*.*.*' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to *.*.*.* ([*.*.*.*]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /root/***.json
```

Is there any way that I can debug this? （like any internal errors, messages, logs)

Thanks very much!

Comment: `-v      Verbose mode.  Causes scp and ssh(1) to print debugging messages about their progress.  This is helpful in debugging connection, authentication, and configuration problems.`

Comment: Check the logs on the receiving side.

Comment: `-v` shows some more information. Let me update them in the question. Thanks @GeraldSchneider

Comment: @istheEnglishway How do I check the receiving side?

Comment: `ssh` then `cd /var/log` and look in them.

Comment: @istheEnglishway there are many log files in that directory, which one should I check?

Comment: I'm going to leave that for you to figure out yourself. It's quite easy.

Comment: Tried my best but I don't know which one is related to `scp`. For the most possible cases, I only found `lastlog` which is a unreadable binary file and `auth.log` which says some mistake logins (maybe attacks)

Comment: I did some Google research and checked the `/var/log/secure' on the receiving side, it says: `Jan 26 04:01:42 localhost sshd[16091]: Accepted publickey for root from *.*.*.* (the Server A) port 37509 ssh2
Jan 26 04:01:43 localhost sshd[16021]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)` then there's no new information.

Comment: And then there are a few breaking-in attempts from Brazil. I guess that's normal?